# MS-Access If Join Unsuccessful, Leave Blank

Tags: database, ms-access

In my DB, I have various joins to other tables of which some are incomplete.

For example, a query to display sales from tblSales and a join to tblEmployees:

```
     tblEmployees
-------------------------
EmployeeName | EmployeeID
-------------------------
Bob          | 123
Sam          | 234

        tblSales
------------------------
Transaction | EmployeeID
------------------------
123456      | 123
123457      | 124
123458      | 234
```

I would like this to display or something along the lines of:

```
    queEmployeeSales
---------------------------
EmployeeName | Transaction
---------------------------
Bob          | 123456      
"ERROR"      | 123457
Sam          | 123458
```

However when access cannot locate the EmployeeID in tblEmployees, it just completely omits the record as such:

```
    queEmployeeSales
---------------------------
EmployeeName | Transaction
---------------------------
Bob          | 123456
Sam          | 123458
```

Is there a way that, should my join be unsuccessful, it will either enter some "invalid" message or leave it completely blank instead of removing the record completely?

Comment: Where is your query? you should change from inner join to left/right join.

Comment: Could you open your query in _SQL View_ rather than _Design View_ and edit your question with the SQL for the query please.  As @krishKM says - it's more than likely that you're using an INNER join which will only returns records that match in both tables.

Comment: It was an inner join, yeah. I looked into the join syntax to get an understanding of what the purpose of the left/right/inner stuff as I just assumed cause it was working before it would work again :P. I was able to get it working with a left join, thank ye for the help. I would like your comments if I could :(